# Parse many large XML files - output when matching tokens occur greater than x seconds apart

Tags: xml, sorting, parsing, large-files, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to find the token pairs that happen greater than x seconds from each other.

XML data looks like this:

```
<entry stamp="2017-10-30T19:19:59" level="MESSAGE" location="Process" message="token is 191"/>
<entry stamp="2017-10-30T19:20:59" level="MESSAGE" location="Process" message="token is 192"/>
<entry stamp="2017-10-30T19:21:59" level="MESSAGE" location="Process" message="token is 193"/>
<entry stamp="2017-10-30T19:22:59" level="MESSAGE" location="Process" message="token is 194"/>
<entry stamp="2017-10-30T19:23:59" level="MESSAGE" location="Process" message="token is 191"/>
<entry stamp="2017-10-30T19:24:59" level="MESSAGE" location="Process" message="token is 192"/>
<entry stamp="2017-10-30T19:25:59" level="MESSAGE" location="Process" message="token is 193"/>
<entry stamp="2017-10-30T19:25:59" level="MESSAGE" location="Process" message="token is 194"/>
```

The actual message is extremely long.  It has a token in each one.

There is a line with a unique IN token and it has a corresponding OUT token.

Normally the IN and OUT tokens happen within a second of each other.

These files are HUGE - 100MB, and there are hundreds of them.

Only a few outliers exist where they occur greater than x seconds apart.

When those lines exist, append to a file.

Any thoughts?  I'm using xmlstarlet, but essentially anything can work if I can grasp the idea and run it on RHEL.

Comment: _"There is a line with a unique IN token and it has a corresponding OUT token."_ -- how does that relate to the XML you've shown?  You must show all relevant information and data if you want help.

Comment: I'm guessing that the first `<entry>` element with a given `@message` is interpreted as an IN token and the second `<entry>` element with the same `@message` is interpreted as a corresponding OUT token. But I might be completely wrong, the explanation certainly isn't clear.

Comment: To save anyone else having to look it up, RHEL = Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

Comment: elaborate your *corresponding OUT token* - if it's a line with some different `message` attribute content - post those lines

Comment: Ah apologies - i was stuck in my own head.  Michael is completely correct.  If a token occurs in a file once, it will occur later in the file a second time.  The first occurrence of "token is 191" is the IN message.  And the second occurrence of "token is 191" is the OUT message.  "token is 191" will not occur again ever after that.  This is the only way we can identify in/out messages that correspond to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using streaming in XSLT 3.0.

```
<xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:iterate select="entry">
    <xsl:param name="unmatched" select="map{}"/>
    <!-- the param contains a map from @message to @stamp -->
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="string(@message)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="time" select="xs:dateTime(@stamp)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="map:contains($unmatched, $token)">
        <xsl:if test="$time - map:get($unmatched, $token)
                       gt xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')">
          <outlier>{$token}</outlier>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:next-iteration>
          <xsl:with-param name="unmatched" 
                          select="map:remove($unmatched, $token)"/>
        </xsl:next-iteration> 
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:next-iteration>
          <xsl:with-param name="unmatched" 
                          select="map:put($unmatched, $token, $time)"/>
        </xsl:next-iteration>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:iterate>
</xsl:template>
```

How it works: perform a streamed iteration over the entry elements, maintaining current state in a map bound to variable `$unmatched`. At any point, the variable holds those tokens for which an IN event has occurred but no OUT event has occurred. When processing a particular entry, first decide whether it is an IN or OUT event based on whether the token is present in this map. If it is an OUT event, compare the timestamp with the IN event and if more than one second later, report it as an outlier; in either case, drop the token from the map. If it is an IN event, continue after adding the token to the map.

In fact, you should be able to process 100Mb without streaming, so you could try this in the free Saxon-HE product with streaming switched off. You only really need to enable streaming when you get above 500Mb or so.